# Rest to JMS bridge in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I was able to set up a REST endpoint in Camel, and I want to bridge it to JMS.  The JMS message is sent, but the body is empty.  I want the body of the JMS message to be the HTTP request in plain text.  How can I achieve this mapping? Debugging I see that the body of the Camel Exchange is an instance of `org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache`

My code looks like this:

```
rest("/test").post("/post ").to("activemq:ao_wsbroker?URL=tcp://localhost:61616");
```

I have tried using the jetty and the restlet components.

Comment: Try with "activemq:ao_wsbrokerURL=tcp://localhost:61616?jmsMessageType=Text"

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it does work. But Christian's solution fits better with other functionality I need to add to my routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add [convertBodyTo(String.class)](http://camel.apache.org/convertbodyto.html) in front of the .to()

Comment: I'm not seeing a convertBodyTo exposed on the RestDefinition.